# What do the numbers behind a library mean?

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, static-libraries

On Linux I see names for libraries like `libpgm-5.1.so.0.0.118` and on OS X I see names like `libhunspell-1.2.0.0.0.dylib`. What do all these numbers mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do all these numbers mean?

These are called external library versioning. You can read a detailed explanation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter5-5/index.html).